# Cross-browser textPath horizontal centre alignment for multi-line text

Tags: svg, cross-browser, text-alignment

I would like to horizontally centre align more than one line of text.

The following approach works in Firefox 68.0.2

```css
path { stroke: #000; }
text { fill: #000; }
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="120">
  <path id="p1" d="M10,40l250,0" />
  <text text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="50%">
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.4em">this is the first line</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.4em">and this is the second</tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

However, in Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90, both lines are rendered to the left. It looks as though the combined length of the two `<tspan>` is used to calculate the centre point.

[image: screenshot from Chrome showing the incorrectly aligned lines]

I can make it work in both browsers by using two separate `<text>` elements:

```css
path { stroke: #000; }
text { fill: #000; }
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="120">
  <path id="p1" d="M10,40l250,0" />
  <text text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="50%">
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.4em">this is the first line</tspan>          
    </textPath>
  </text>
  <text text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="50%">
      <tspan x="0" dy="2.8em">and this is the second</tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

(I also tried using two `<textPath>` within the same `<text>` parent, but the behaviour of `dy` is also different between the two browsers)

My questions are:

1. Which browser is behaving correctly (is this a bug in the other one)?
2. Is there a cross-browser way to achieve the same result without rendering two separate `<text>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Chrome is doing the correct thing here - other than the missing "a". :-/

In SVG 1.1, the interaction of the `startOffset` and `x` attributes wasn't well defined, and browsers did all different things.

However, in SVG 2, an attempt to fully describe the text layout algorithm for `<textPath>` elements has been made.  You can find it here:

https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextpathLayoutRules

In there it says:

> For text-anchor:middle, startpoint-on-the-path is the point on the path which represents the point on the path which is [ ‘startOffset’ minus half of the total advance values for all of the glyphs in the ‘textPath’ element ] distance along the path from the start of the path

Then later, it says:

> When the inline-base direction is horizontal, then any ‘x’ attributes on ‘text’ or ‘tspan’ elements represent new absolute offsets along the path, thus providing explicit new values for startpoint-on-the-path.

In other words, your `x="0"` attributes are overriding the `startOffset` and `text-anchor` settings.

So being more simple and explicit, as you are in your second SVG, is the way to go.